# how can remove place in custom google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps. I need to map only I, but as you can see in the picture, there are places.
Can I remove them?
[place in map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNpj0.jpg)

Comment: Please elaborate your question a little bit more like. Platform. Web(PHP)?, Android etc.

Comment: in web asp.net mvc but i find answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find answer only need add this code to the init function

```
styles: [{ "featureType": "poi.business", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "labels.text", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }],
```